# Comparing function results against API in Chai?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

I'm quite new to JavaScript, and I've made a Node module which works, but I want to add some testing using Mocha and Chai.

My node module returns the results of TVmaze API.  The module is called tvmaze-node and is available through NPM.

For example, the following will return the results of http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls

```
 pullRequest: function(url, donePulledRequest) {
    request(url, function(error, response, body){
      if(error || response.statusCode === 404 || body.length == 2) {
         donePulledRequest(error || 'No results');
      }
      else {
        donePulledRequest(null, JSON.parse(body));
      }
    });
  },

  search: function(show, doneShow){
    var url =  "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=" + show;
    module.exports.pullRequest(url, doneShow)
  },
```

What I would like to do in Chai is to make sure that the results of **search** match the json returned from a URL.

I've got the structure for Chai, but can't figure the logic out of the life of me.  For some reason I get the error:

> Uncaught AssertionError: expected [ Array(10) ] to deeply equal
>   '[{"score":2.096719,"show":{......*the rest of the array shown at the URL above*

```
describe('Show Search', function() {
  it("Returns all results for a given search", function(done) {
tvmaze.search("Lost", function(error, response) {
  if(error){
    done(error);
  } else {
  request('http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=lost', function(error, resp, body){
    expect(response).to.eql(body);
      done();
    })
  }
});
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: The error shows it clearly, the `reponse` is an array, whereas the `body` is  json, they cannot be compared through `eql`? Also both `q=lost` and `q=Lost` return the same result? if the results are same, `JSON.parse(body)` equal to `body`?

Comment: If I do `expect(response).to.equal(JSON.parse(body))` then the response and the body should be identical.  This then gives me the error       `Uncaught AssertionError: expected [ Array(10) ] to equal [ Array(10) ]
      + expected - actual`

Comment: To compare deep in array, please try `expect(response).to.eql(JSON.parse(body))`? `.equal` just compare objects rather than their data

Comment: That appears to have worked!  Many thanks!  Might be worth adding that as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: sure, I will summary it as one answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the code `donePulledRequest(null, JSON.parse(body));`, you should check the value in the test code as below.

```
expect(response).to.eql(JSON.parse(body))
```